# How do you get more storage in the Replit Database (@replit/database)?

Tags: replit, replit-database

I am distributing a product based on Replit and it’s already out of storage. I’ve seen that the Replit hacker plan can add more local storage, but I can’t find anything regarding the database. Is there any way to get more storage?

Comment: Hacker Pro just got released, and I believe they will be adding a way to pay for more storage with cycles

Answer (score 0):

You could buy some more storage. Go to your Replit home page, and go to "My cycles" and then go to the place where it says "or choose a Hacker or Teams Pro plan instead" and click on the link. You can pay $7.00 a month for 2 gigs of storage. One more thing you could do is make a GitHub page, and Iframe that page, but this would only work for files that are independent from the rest of the code or are independent scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the only way is to pay for them. It might be changed later, but for right now paying is the only way.